# Please evaluate the limit and check the correctness of my answer

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+n^2}+\frac{2}{2+n^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n+n^2}\right)$$

My answer is coming $0$ but the answer given is $\frac12$. Please review. Thanks.

**EDIT**

we can re-write the expression as $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{0n^2+1}{n^2+1}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{0n^2+2}{n^2+2}+\cdots+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{0n^2+n}{n^2+n}$$ $$=\frac01+\frac01+\cdots+\frac01$$ $$=0$$

Comment: Without putting too much thought into it, I can definitely say that $0$ is not correct. If you want further feedback on your solution, we'll have to see some details about it.

Comment: You should add more detail on how you get $0$ as solution.

Comment: @user let me edit it

Comment: You can't use the given argument since here we are not dealing with a fixed number of terms.

Comment: @user then i dont know how to do it

Comment: This doesn't make sense, like $1+1=1+0+1+0=0$

Comment: A way is by squeeze theorem bounding the sum.

Comment: The thing is, it’s not 0+0+0+…. . It is (something very small)+ (something very small)+ (something very small)+ (something very small)+…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lower bound
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{i\over i+n^2}>\sum_{i=1}^n {i\over n+n^2}=\frac12{n(n+1)\over n(n+1)}=\frac12$$ since $\sum^n_1 i=\frac12n(n+1)$
and an upper bound
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{i\over i+n^2}<\sum_{i=1}^n {i\over n^2}=\frac12{n(n+1)\over n^2}=\frac12+{1\over 2n}.$$

Comment: Have you used squeeze theorm $?$

Comment: You are approaching 10k, so may be it's time you get familiar with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bn%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B2%2Bn%5E2%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2B%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bn%2Bn%5E2%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1)